# Camelot-py not detecting tables with two rows

Tags: python, python-camelot

Scraping table data from a .PDF using Camelot-py, and it is not detecting tables with 2/1 rows.

**PDF I am trying to read:**
[image]

Code used to read tables:

```
abc = camelot.read_pdf('IR-O-U-0436.pdf', pages="all")
```

**The output I am getting:**
[image]

From the images, you can see that sponsored research table is being read in abc[15] and the second part of the consultancy project details table is being read in abc[16] but the first part of the consultancy project details table is being missed by Camelot.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To obtain useful help, please provide the original PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar tables in some of the pdfs which were not detected by camelot. But after passing the parameter "line_scale" to read_pdf function, I was able to detect these tables as well.
You have to get that specific value for "line_scale" parameter which will give you all tables irrespective of the row number.
For me

> line_scale = 35

worked fine. You can check for yourself.